# Iterate QAction items on a given QToolBar object in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qaction, qtoolbar

Using Python and PyQt4, given a GUI with any number of QToolBar objects and each toolbar contains any number of QAction objects.

I can iterate the ui with the following code and find the toolbars:

```
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(ui):
    if isinstance(obj, QToolBar):
        print "toolbar =",name
```

How can I iterate each toolbar object and find the QAction objects.  I will then read the QActions to determine which are "checked".  I am not using QActionGroups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the toolbars were created in Qt Designer, they will become children of the main window (or whatever the top-level widget is).

So you can simply do:

```
for toolbar in mainwindow.findChildren(QToolBar):
    print('toolbar: %s' % toolbar.objectName())
    for action in toolbar.actions():
        if not action.isSeparator():
            print('  action: %s (%s)' % (action.text(), action.isChecked()))
```

Comment: Thanks... I will test both suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: Wow! That is perfect.  Exactly what I needed and then some.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given a QToolBar you can find all of its QActions by calling its [`actions`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#actions) method:

> Returns the (possibly empty) list of this widget's actions.

For example:

```
if isinstance(obj, QToolBar):
    print obj.actions()
```